# Flex extending ComboBox

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, combobox, flex4

I created a class `CustomCombo.as` that extends `ComboBox`. What is happening is that the `CustomCombo` combobox is showing as being editable. I do not want this and I cant find the properties to set the `editable` to `false`.

I also tried setting the combobox's `textInput.editable` control to `false`, but to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

`CustomCombo.as`

```
package custom {

    import spark.components.ComboBox;

    public class CustomCombo extends ComboBox {

        public function CustomCombo() {
            super();
//          this.editable = false; //<-- THIS DOESNT WORK   ***Access of possibly undefined property editable through a reference with static type custom:CustomCombo
//          this.textInput.editable = false; //<-- THIS DOESNT WORK   ***Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After rummaging through the Flex 4 API I found that they suggest to use the `DropDownList` control. From what I can see is that they removed the `editable` property from the `ComboBox` control in Flex 4, but I may be wrong.

I implemented `DropDownList` and that solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you're using spark and not mx. The `editable` property I referred to is applicable only to mx based list. In spark, [ComboBox](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/ComboBox.html) extends `DropDownListBase` and is editable by default.

> The `ComboBox` control is a child class of the `DropDownListBase` control. Like the `DropDownListBase` control, when the user selects an item from the drop-down list in the `ComboBox` control, the data item appears in the prompt area of the control.
>
> One difference between the controls is that the prompt area of the `ComboBox` control is implemented by using the `TextInput` control, instead of the `Label` control for the `DropDownList` control. Therefore, a user can edit the prompt area of the control to enter a value that is not one of the predefined options.
>
> For example, the `DropDownList` control only lets the user select from a list of predefined items in the control. The `ComboBox` control lets the user either select a predefined item, or enter a new item into the prompt area. Your application can recognize that a new item has been entered and, optionally, add it to the list of items in the control.
>
> The `ComboBox` control also searches the item list as the user enters characters into the prompt area. As the user enters characters, the drop-down area of the control opens. It then and scrolls to and highlights the closest match in the item list.

So ideally, you should be using `DropDownList` in this case.

You're getting null error when trying to access `textInput` from the constructor because it hasn't been created yet. In mx based controls (Flex-3), you can access it from the `creationComplete` handler; I'm not quite sure how to do it for spark based controls.

Update: I think I've figured out how to access skin parts in spark (though you might wanna use the `DropDownBox` instead). You have to override the `partAdded` method.

```
override protected function partAdded(partName:String, instance:Object):void
{
    super.partAdded(partName, instance);
    if (instance == textInput)
    {
        textInput.editable = false;
    }
}
```

There's one catch though: it may not work in this case. The [source code of ComboBox.as](http://opensource.adobe.com/svn/opensource/flex/sdk/trunk/frameworks/projects/spark/src/spark/components/ComboBox.as) says that

> the API ignores the visual `editable` and `selectable` properties

So `DropDownList` it is!

---

Initial answer, posted for mx `ComboBox`.

This shouldn't happen as the default value of the [editable](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/ComboBase.html#editable) property is `false`.

Try explicitly setting the value to `false` from the constructor.

```
public function CustomCombo() {
  super();
  this.editable = false;
}
```

Comment: I already tried that. I get the following error; 'Access of possibly undefined property editable through a reference with static type custom:CustomCombo'.

Comment: +1 For trying to help, but I found a solution in the Flex 4 API. See my posted answer

Comment: @Pieter Glad you figured it out yourself. See my update - not really helpful in this particular case, but might prove useful later.